# Difference in memory consumption between spark streaming job vs spark batch job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to write CSV file from local to HDFS in parquet format by spark streaming job. Size of file is 4GB.
i am getting below error:

```
[Stage 3:>                                                         (0 + 8) / 32]20/12/28 08:36:04 ERROR Utils: Aborting task
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.ensureSize(ResizableArray.scala:103)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.ensureSize(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:99)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.mutable.BufferLike$class.appendAll(BufferLike.scala:148)
        at scala.collection.mutable.AbstractBuffer.appendAll(Buffer.scala:49)
        at scala.collection.mutable.BufferLike$class.append(BufferLike.scala:143)
```

I am using below code in pyspark:

```
pyspark --num-executors 5 --driver-memory 2g --executor-memory 2g
df_str = spark.readStream.format("csv").schema(sch).option("header",True).option("delimiter",','). load("<Path_to_csv>")
query = df_str.writeStream.format("parquet").outputMode("append").option("path","<Target Loc>").option("checkpointLocation","<checkpoint Location>").start()
```

I tried to load same file through batch Spark job and there is no out of memory error.

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema", "true").option("header",True).option("delimiter",',').load("<Path>")
df.write.format("parquet").mode("append").save("<Target Path>")
```

I am not sure why same file has been work with batch job and not working with streaming job. What I am missing here?

Comment: Did u check increasing the executor memory?

Comment: @Rakshith, I increased to 2GB, after that spark batch is working fine but not spark streaming job, still i did not get why streaming job is not working

Comment: It is possible that the shuffles are creating more havock in streaming. What is the size of your dataset? I think increasing the Spark Executor memory would actually make a difference

Comment: I will check by increasing memory but do you know difference between batch and streaming job memory consumption and is there any other way to handle this as size of dataset can be increased

Comment: Are you using a local master? Do you have at least 12G of memory? (5 executors of 2g + driver 2g)? I think the difference is that the batch knows how large the file is and will adjust the number of executors appropriately